# Printer (Epson WF-3540) driver install consistently freezes on 13.10 but not 12.04

Tags: drivers, 13.10, printing

When I try to add my printer, the system detects the driver but freezes partway through installing it. How can I add the printer?

Some details:

- The printer is being connected over wifi and works fine with other computers- including a older laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.
- The printer is an epson WF-3540.
- I'm running 13.10.

I've attatched a picture of what happens.

[image: printer install windows]

Comment: Is there any information I could provide or anything I could look into to start troubleshooting?

Comment: Having the same issues with this printer.  You can downoad the 'full' driver package from Epson's website and install the .deb yourself and it works.  Scanning is still a pain though.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well with an Epson WF-7525 driver (`epson-escpr`) on 13.10. Installation can't be canceled, and force quitting leaves apt-get locked.

Comment: I could more elegantly cancel the installation by sending a sigterm to the `install-printer` process.